# How to convert XML hierarchy to table with XSLT 1.0?

Tags: html, xml, html-table, xslt-1.0, hierarchy

I'm trying to convert this XML hierarchy to an HTML table

```
<TopTerm Id="1" Name="Company">
  <narrower Id="2" Name="Office">
    <narrower Id="2.1" Name="Desk">
      <narrower Id="2.1.1" Name="PC"/>
    </narrower>
    <narrower Id="2.2" Name="Cabinet">
      <narrower Id="2.2.1" Name="Folder"/>
      <narrower Id="2.2.2" Name="Files"/>
    </narrower>
  </narrower>
</TopTerm>
```

Desired output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Level 1</th>
        <th>Level 2</th>
        <th>Level 3</th>
        <th>Level 4</th>
        <th>Id</th>             
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>Office</td> 
        <td></td>
        <td></td>       
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>Office</td> 
        <td>Desk</td>
        <td></td>       
        <td>2.1</td>
   </tr>                
</table>
```

Basically it needs to create 1 `<tr>` for each hierarchy level and includes its ancestors.

I use this XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Level 1</th>
            <th>Level 2</th>
            <th>Level 3</th>
            <th>Level 4</th>
            <th>Id</th>             
        </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//TopTerm"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="TopTerm">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant-or-self::narrower"/>    
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="narrower">
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>            
      </xsl:for-each>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></td> <!--Problem is here-->
   </tr>
 </xsl:template>
```

The problem is the `<td>` for Id is not always in the correct position because the number of ancestors in each level are different. How do I get the correct Id for each node and put in it in the correct Id column?

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach, I can add the required `<td>` by counting the number of ancestors of the current node.

```
<xsl:template match="narrower">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                </td>            
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:if test="count(ancestor-or-self::*) = 1">
                <td/>
                <td/>
                <td/>
                <td/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(ancestor-or-self::*) = 2">
                <td/>
                <td/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="count(ancestor-or-self::*) = 3">
                <td/>
            </xsl:if>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
            </td>           
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
```